# Why mist is not working properly

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, private-blockchain

I have established a private network and connected with 2 nodes. And I opened the mist using terminal with the command

> "open -a /Applications/Mist.app --args --rpc/usr/local/Cellar/test1/geth.ipc "

mist shows a test network rinkbey I changed as solo network now it shows private-network but I am not connected with these 2 nodes. And when I start mining blocks are not increasing and ethers shows 0

Comment: ``--rpc /usr/local/Cellar/test1/geth.ipc`` space missing?

Comment: where space is missing

Comment: Compare with your post. There is no space in your command.